# Show a floating navigation bar on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, blogger

I am using blogspot, and I wanted to exactly achieve this kind of floating navigation bar:

http://apairandasparediy.com/

As you can see, when you scroll, the floating navigation bar shows as it slides down.

All I know is make a navigation bar:

```
<div id="floating-nav-content">
   <div class="floating-nav">
      <ul id="menu-floating-menu" class="menu">
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

But the rest of the jQuery or javascript stuff is still unknown to me. I have also search but they don't teach exactly what I want.

I'm only new to jQuery and I still have no idea how to implement this.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want. (assuming you've already included the jQuery library)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
                $("#floating-nav-content").slideUp(400);
            } else {
                $("#floating-nav-content").slideDown(600);
            }

        });
    </script>
```

The CSS is also important, because this places the navigation bar in a fixed position on top of your page.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #floating-nav-content {
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #000;
            position: fixed;
            display: none;
            color: #FFF;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
```

And ofcourse the HTML.
I placed all of the above and below in the body tag.

```
    <div id="floating-nav-content">
        Content
    </div>
```

Comment: Obviously, some styling is missing here, compared to your example, but I'm sure you can figure that out yourself ;) Good luck

Comment: thank you! but problem is when the page is loaded, the floating nav bar is visible by default. how do I hide it and it will only show up when I scroll down?

Comment: Use the "display: none;" property in your CSS. additionally, if for any reason that will not work (it should!), you could resolve it using **$("#floating-nav-bar").hide();** at the top of your script.

Comment: oh I forgot. now it's working perfectly. thanks a lot!

Comment: how do I let the floating nav show only when it reach a certain point in my page, say when I scroll and my page header image reaches the top then that will be the time the floating nav bar will show

Comment: Depending on the height of your header, you can play with the value of scrollTop(). eg: **if ($(this).scrollTop() < 220)**